# HttpWebRequest submit

Tags: .net

Sorry for such popular question, but,
i don't need fill anything, i just need press a submit button on html page, how can i do it, via HttpWebRequest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to know:

- Whether there are any hidden pre-populated fields or other data required for the submission
- The URL to submit to
- The HTTP method (GET/POST)

But yes, it can all be done with `HttpWebRequest`.

If you don't have any extra data, it may be as simple as creating the web request, setting the method appropriately, and then calling `GetResponse`. If you need to include data, it may be in the query part of the URL (if it's a GET request) or the body (if it's a POST request).

Comment: its POST, and page doesnt have hidden fields, its authentification from key token on flash drive, so i dont have to fill anything, just submit, that i want to enter the page

Comment: sorry, my fault, its was easy